# Integer Division with random.randint

Tags: python, integer-division

When using random.randint() in this form, I can't get integer division to work:

```
(random.randint(-40, 215) - -40) // (215 - -40)
```

This returns 0, however something like this returns correctly:

```
random.randint(3,5) - 2 // 2
```

How do I format the first equation correctly to get a rounded integer instead of defaulting to 0?

Comment: Your first equation is correct: it converts it to the `[0,1)` interval. Since you use integer division the result is thus always 0.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone runs into this when normalizing integers, here is a normalization between -40 and 215:

```
(random.randint(-40,215) - -40.0) * 10 // (215.0 - -40.0) * 10
```

Kudos to Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the non int answer

```
print (random.randint(-40, 215) +40.0) / (215+40)
```

The result lies always between `(0,1)` step of which is always 0 and hence it returns always zero.